# Tuple elements to dataframe column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have 2D lists containing 0-3 sets of pairs (data will always be paired).

examples:

```
[[2.0, 0.1], [7.0, 0.6], [1.0, 0.3]] or
[[9.0, 0.7], [1.0, 0.2]]             or
[[]]
```

**I want to be able to append each element of each pair to its own column in an existing dataframe.**

Desired dataframe using above data:

```
other_data,    pair_0_0, pair_0_1, pair_1_0, pair_1_1, pair_2_0, pair2_1
'blah',        2.0,      0.1,      7.0,      0.6,      1.0,      0.3    
'blah blah',   9.0,      0.7,      1.0,      0.2
'blaah'
```

It needs to be able to handle nulls, and preserve the order of the list.

I've tried the following, but it can't it gives an index error if i don't have 3 pairs.

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['blah blah', list2D[0][0], list2D[0][1], list2D[1][0], list2D[1][1], list2D[2][0], list2D[2][1]
```

I think it would involve some list comprehension, but i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I’m curious, what’s the use case for this?

Comment: part of turning BLOBs of vibration spectra into a spreadsheet that shows 3 dominant peaks [Frequency & Amplitude] for each measurement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) in a list comprehension:

```
l1 = [[2.0, 0.1], [7.0, 0.6], [1.0, 0.3]]
l2 = [[9.0, 0.7], [1.0, 0.2]]
l3 = [[]]

df = pd.DataFrame([np.ravel(x) for x in [l1, l2, l3]])

# Fix column headers
df.columns = [f'pair_{x//2}_{x%2}' for x in range(df.shape[1])]
```

[out]

```
   pair_0_0  pair_0_1  pair_1_0  pair_1_1  pair_2_0  pair_2_1
0       2.0       0.1       7.0       0.6       1.0       0.3
1       9.0       0.7       1.0       0.2       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

---

#### Update

To [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) an individual list to an existing `DataFrame` for example, use:

```
l4 = [[3.0, 0.2], [6.0, 0.8], [1.2, 0.6]]

df.append(pd.DataFrame([np.ravel(l4)]).rename(columns=lambda x: f'pair_{x//2}_{x%2}'))
```

[out]

```
   pair_0_0  pair_0_1  pair_1_0  pair_1_1  pair_2_0  pair_2_1
0       2.0       0.1       7.0       0.6       1.0       0.3
1       9.0       0.7       1.0       0.2       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
0       3.0       0.2       6.0       0.8       1.2       0.6
```

Or using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in a loop to create a `DataFrame` from scratch you could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for l in  [l1, l2, l3]:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([np.ravel(l)]).rename(columns=lambda x: f'pair_{x//2}_{x%2}')],
                   sort=True)
```

Comment: This is great, but how would i add just one 2D list to an existing dataframe? I'm going to be doing this all in a loop.

Comment: @RoryLM Should be able to use the aptly-named `.append()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm using the append method now which is working great, but i just need to include another value when appending. (see 'other_data' in original question). I tried the following but i got a dataframe constructor error: `df.append(pd.DataFrame('placeholder value',[np.ravel(l4)]).rename(...)))`

Comment: How about `assign`... ie `df.append(pd.DataFrame([np.ravel(l4)]).rename(columns=lambda x: f'pair_{x//2}_{x%2}').assign(other_data='placeholder value'))`

Comment: Any reason you chose to use Numpy's `ravel()` to flatten the 2D list? I've learned that this can also be done using `chain.iterable()` or even just list comprehension without imports. using ravel caused me problems down the line because it converts everything to numpy strings if there are any stings in the initial 2D lists (which there now are)

Answer (score 1):

Another very simple way is using Python dict comprehension to insert a new entry e:

```
row = {f'pair_{j}_{i}': e[j][i] for j in range(len(e)) for i in range(len(e[j]))}
```

Example:

```
e1 = [[2.0, 0.1], [7.0, 0.6], [1.0, 0.3]]
e2 = [[9.0, 0.7], [1.0, 0.2]]
e3 = [[]]

df = pd.DataFrame({})

for e in [e1, e2, e3]:
    row = {f'pair_{j}_{i}': e[j][i] for j in range(len(e)) for i in range(len(e[j]))}
    df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

print(df)

```
   pair_0_0  pair_0_1  pair_1_0  pair_1_1  pair_2_0  pair_2_1
0       2.0       0.1       7.0       0.6       1.0       0.3
1       9.0       0.7       1.0       0.2       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```